# Paired sample t test with different scales

Tags: mathematical-statistics, spss, paired-data

We recently did an online survey with our customers. There are 2 particular questions, that all of them filled in, on which I want to do some statistical analysis. The problem is that the scale of the first question is a scale with 4 answers and the second question has 5 possible answers.

e.g.

Q1:
Very satisfied - 
Somewhat satisfied -
Somewhat dissatisfied -
Very dissatisfied

Q2: Definitely would recommend - probably would - might or might not - probably would not - definitely would not recommend

I've read that a paired sample t test can only be conducted if the two questions are based on the same scale.

Is there a way how I can fix this? (btw we use SPSS at our company)

Comment: Regardless of the number of potential responses in the answers, I don't see how it makes sense to compare a "probably would" type of measurement to a "satisfied" type of measurement.  It would be like asking if the sky is bluer than a child is happy.  What are you trying to determine about the responses to these questions?

Comment: Comparing these two questions with a t-test makes no sense to me. What are you trying to find out?

Comment: @SalMangiafico I am trying to find out if the testsubjects are more likely to give a higher score on Q1 than on Q2.

Comment: @PeterFlom I am trying to find out if the testsubjects are more likely to give a higher score on Q1 than on Q2. The responses are coded 1-4 for the first question and 1-5 for the 2nd one.

Comment: Yes, I think asking which question has higher responses doesn't make sense because the questions are measuring two different things.  (A little less far-out than my earlier example), it would be like asking if the U.S. has a higher income or teen pregnancy rate.  Well, the median income is $50,000 per household, and 22.2 births per 1000 are by women less than 20 years old. So, which is higher? ...

Comment: ... There may be a temptation to convert the question responses to a percentage, like 4/5 = .80, and so on.  There are a few problems with this, but one I'll point out is that it's not clear what 100% would be, especially as the scales of the questions vary.  For example, out of disagree/neutral/agree, "agree" is "100%"; out of .../agree/strongly-agree, "strongly-agree" is "100%", out of .../strong-agree/really-strongly-agree, "really-strongly-agree" is "100%".

Answer (score 1):

In a comment the OP said

> I am trying to find out if the testsubjects are more likely to give a
>   higher score on Q1 than on Q2. The responses are coded 1-4 for the
>   first question and 1-5 for the 2nd one.

I don't think this can be done in any sensible way.  Not only are 1-4 and 1-5 different (that might be dealt with) but the underlying scales are incommensurate. In what way is (say) "very satisfied" like "definitely would recommend"?

Comment: what about wilcoxon signed rank test?

Comment: @rep_ho How would that help?  I think the problem is that the scales are incommensurate.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, the research question doesn't make sense